# Is there a way to create a controller for specific xtypes/containers?

Tags: extjs, controller, xtype

I have forms built with different components that load and edit the same records in different ways.

Overall, I have a viewController for these records which handles the loading and saving of the forms. All the forms have a 'load' and 'save' button which is handled in this 'recordController'.

However, because of the different containers I created that can be used to view the records, some paginated or expandable, I have functions that handle the buttons 'next page', 'prev page', 'expand info' contained in the recordController.

I want to remove these functions 'next page', 'prev page', and 'expand info' from the recordController and place them into controllers specific to the xtypes I made them for. This way, I can create components with the same functionality without duplicating the functions in the code.

I know I can put these functions into a 'masterController' that all other controllers inherit from, however as time goes on the masterController would grow and can become difficult to manage/change functionality of. Ideally neither controller inherits from the other.

Basically the concept of what I'm trying to do is:

```
Ext.define('CustomForm', {
     controller: 'recordController',
     items: [{
           xtype: 'tabpanel',
           controller: 'tabpanelController'
     }]
};
```

Obviously the above doesn't work, but if it did ideally function calls in the tabpanel would default to the tabpanelController before heading to the recordController, without the tabpanelController being a descendant of the record controller.

Is there a way to accomplish this concept?

Comment: Your sample code is the same inheritance. tabpanelController extends recordController and overrides some methods. Why are you trying to create new inheritance mechanisms?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by 'is the same inheritance'. I don't have tabpanelController extending the recordController in the example above. If I tried to call a function in the recordController from the tabpanel with that setup, it wouldn't go through to the recordController. I don't want to define a function 'Next Tab' in the recordController since it has nothing to do with the record and only the tabpanel. This way I can define a tabpanel anywhere and still use that function without redefining it.

Comment: But you can define your own tabpanel which will extend the standard one and register there appropriate controller. Why do you need to register two controllers in the same view?

Comment: This sounds like a perfect place for either - a mixin, which keeps the same controller functionality for all controllers or - you define a form with a controller and extend that form and the viewController inside the inherited viewController.